# Form validation just for one button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm new in web development. I have a form with two buttons, i have a javascript function to validate a form when it is submitted:

```
function validateForm() {
        var freq = document.forms["schedulerForm"]["frequency"].value;
        if(freq == null || freq ==""){
            alert("Please select a frequency!");
            return false;
        }

        var freqValue = document.forms["schedulerForm"]["frequencyValue"].value;
        if (freqValue == null || freqValue == "") {
            alert("Please enter a frequency value!");
            return false;
        }

        var email = document.forms["schedulerForm"]["email"].value;
        if (email == null || email == "") {
            alert("Please add an email!");
            return false;
        }       
    }
```

And the Form: (Adapted for the question purpose)

```
    <form method="post" id="schedulerForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="frequency" name="frequency" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select a Frequency</option>
                    <option value="seconds">Seconds</option>
                    <option value="minutes">Minutes</option>
                    <option value="hours">Hours</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="frequencyValue" id="frequencyValue"> 
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter an email" data-items="8">

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnStart" value="Start Scheduler" onclick="testScheduler('start')"/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnStop" value="Stop Scheduler" onclick="testScheduler('stop')"/>
</form>
```

It is working, the function validation works, but i want to restrict this validation just for the first button and not for the other, I thought to take out the second button, but if i do that the form will not be submitted.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want both buttons to submit the form, but only 'start' to valid the form before submitting. Remove the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` from the form and add it to the onclick of the button.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnStart" value="Start Scheduler" onclick="testScheduler('start'); return validateForm();"/>
```

There are other ways but this would be easiest.